# RegisterStartupScript and order of execution

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to register calls to a large number of JS functions.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Script1", "SomeScript1", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Script2", "SomeScript1", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "EndScript", "EndScript", true);
```

When the HTML is rendered, it's adding them in order.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
other functions calls..
SomeScript1();SomeScript2();EndScript();
//]]>
</script>
```

However, when I step through in debug mode, the execution of scripts are not in order (Ex: `EndScript` executes first before `SomeScript1` or `SomeScript2`)

Doesn't `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` gaurantee execution in the order it was added? If not, what are the alternatives (I want to always execute `EndScript` in the end)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the MSDN page for [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx):

> Startup script blocks that are registered by using [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) are not guaranteed to be output in the same order in which they are registered. If the order of the startup script blocks is important, use a  [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) object to gather the script blocks in a single string, and then register them all as a single startup script.

After they're rendered to the page, the actual execution of the scripts is handled by the browser, and doesn't have anything to do with the `ScriptManager` control.  Looking at the example you have posted, the browser should execute those in the order they're written.  Could your `EndScript` function be called by something else on the page, as well?  Also, if you're using any sort of callbacks, then the timing of when the callback completes is indeterminate.  Can you provide an example of the code that is in each of those scripts?

Comment: But they are added in the correct order. Is the MSDN link implying that they will be added in the correct order but not executed in the order it was added? Unfortunately, I can't gather all the script blocks to a single string. Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

The output you have shown is guaranteed to run in that order.

It is possible that `EndScript` begins executing before `SomeScriptX()` has completed their work if `SomeScriptX` issue calls to `setTimeout` from within their bodies.

Or, perhaps "other functions calls.." is invoking `EndScript()` somewhere deep.

Either way, if you can guarantee that `ScriptManager` is rendering that exact order in its output, then that is the order JavaScript will execute them in.